# TCPDF: How to update database print status if pdf is printed

Tags: php, codeigniter, tcpdf

I am using Codeigniter with TCPDF. Somehow our client requires an indication if that the pdf's already been printed. I created a table for the pdf, file_id, file_type, file_src, file_print_status.

That print button in google chrome to view my pdf, once that button is clicked. the file_print_status will be updated from "N" to "Y".

I only have the logic, once client viewed the pdf and clicked print button in pdf, there's a corresponding update gonna happen based on an ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make sure the PDF was actually printed use the *onafterprint* event.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onafterprint

The **file_print_status** column should be of type **tinyint** with a defualt value of 0 (0 for N, 1 for Y). On the **onafterprint** event just make an Ajax request and update the column to 1.